# How to remove Chrome proposals on my websites search bar?

Tags: html, wordpress, google-chrome, search

When a user clicks on my website, chrome will suggest former searches, the user have searched for on other websites. How can I disable that for all users?

It looks like this:
[image]

Thank You!

Comment: Rename the field. Browsers save the history for a field's name.

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill as it concern prevent auto-fill of inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of the name of your input field. Chrome save these suggestions by a fieldname. Change the name of this input and the suggestions are gone.